# Is there a way to get list of specific element in JSON using C# and Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Im trying to get a list of all the  "Occupants" and "RiskId" from the JSON below using C# and Newtonsoft.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for your help.

```
{
    "Header": {
        "MatchType": "Exact",
        "TotalResultCount": 2,
        "PreviousPageUrl": null,
        "NextPageUrl": null,
        "AvailableProductsForRequestedAddress": "https://prometrixapiuat.iso.com/uw/address/productList?City=MONTEBELLO&State=CA&StreetName=423+W+OLYMPIC+BLVD&Zip=90640"
    },
    "Risks": [
        {
            "RiskId": "64CX99016399",
            "BuildingDescription": "MONTEBELLO PLASTICS INC (1S)",
            "SurveyDates": {
                "ScheduleAppliedDate": "04/21/1999",
                "LatestPhoneSurveyDate": "",
                "OnsiteSurveyDate": "05/01/1999"
            },
            "Location": {
                "Latitude": null,
                "Longitude": null,
                "Address": {
                    "StreetAddress1": "423 W OLYMPIC BLVD",
                    "City": "MONTEBELLO",
                    "PostalCity": "MONTEBELLO",
                    "State": "CA",
                    "Zip": "90640",
                    "Zip4": "5225",
                    "County": "LOS ANGELES"
                },
                "AlternateAddresses": []
            },
            "Occupants": [
                {
                    "Name": "MFG STORAGE - PACKAGING MATERIALS",
                    "OccupantId": "15"
                }
            ],
            "ProductListUrl": "https://prometrixapiuat.iso.com/uw/Risk/64CX99016399/ProductList",
            "YearBuilt": 1960,
            "FireProtectionArea": "MONTEBELLO"
        },
        {
            "RiskId": "64CX99016400",
            "BuildingDescription": "MONTEBELLO PLASTICS INC (1S)",
            "SurveyDates": {
                "ScheduleAppliedDate": "04/21/1999",
                "LatestPhoneSurveyDate": "",
                "OnsiteSurveyDate": "05/01/1999"
            },
            "Location": {
                "Latitude": null,
                "Longitude": null,
                "Address": {
                    "StreetAddress1": "423 W OLYMPIC BLVD",
                    "City": "MONTEBELLO",
                    "PostalCity": "MONTEBELLO",
                    "State": "CA",
                    "Zip": "90640",
                    "Zip4": "5225",
                    "County": "LOS ANGELES"
                },
                "AlternateAddresses": []
            },
            "Occupants": [
                {
                    "Name": "MFG STORAGE - PACKAGING MATERIALS",
                    "OccupantId": "15"
                }
            ],
            "ProductListUrl": "https://prometrixapiuat.iso.com/uw/Risk/64CX99016400/ProductList",
            "YearBuilt": 1960,
            "FireProtectionArea": "MONTEBELLO"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would just like to loop through the list of  "RiskId" and "Occupants" and display the value.

If I do ....

```
var jsonObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);

var jsonResult = jsonObj.SelectToken("Risks.RiskId").Select(m => m.Value<string>());
```

I'm getting below error

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source'

Comment: you are better off using a strongly typed model instead of JObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I showed you this kind of code yesterday

```
JArray risks = (JArray) JObject.Parse(jsonstring)["Risks"];

var riskId = risks.Select(r => (string) r["RiskId"] ).FirstOrDefault(); // "64CX99016400"
    
JArray occupants = risks.Select(r => (JArray) r["Occupants"] ).FirstOrDefault());
```

UPDATE

after @dbc update, if  you can have several  risks items, just remove firstordefault()

```
string[] riskIds = risks.Select(r => (string) r["RiskId"] );

Response.Write(string.Join(", ",riskIds)); // "64CX99016399, 64CX99016400"

List<JArray> occupants = risks.Select(r => (JArray) r["Occupants"] ).ToList();

int[] occupantIds = occupants.SelectMany(o => 
                                o.Select(o => (int)o["OccupantId"])).ToArray();

Response.Write(string.Join(", ",occupantIds)); // "15, 15";
```

Comment: JObject json = JObject.Parse(x.ToString());
                    var riskIds = json["Risks"]
                                    .Select(r => r["RiskId"].ToString())
                                    .ToList();
                    foreach (var id in riskIds)
                    {
                       Response.Write(id);
                    }

Answer (score 1):

You may do:

```
var jsonResult = jsonObj.SelectTokens("Risks[*].RiskId")
    .Select(m => m.Value<string>())
    .ToList();
```

Notes:

1. The `"RiskId"` properties are nested in an array of objects `Risks[*].RiskId`, thus an array indexer such as `[*]` or `[0]` must be included in the path.  `[*]` selects **all** `RiskId` properties.
2. Since the `"RiskId"` properties are in an array and there is more than one, use [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) rather than `SelectToken()` to get them all.
3. If you are unsure of the path to use to select a property by name, you may use the **recursive descent** operator `..` to select all properties with that name, and then use [`JToken.Path`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm) to get the actual path of each.

   Thus, for your JSON,

   ```
   var paths = jsonObj.SelectTokens("...RiskId").Select(m => m.Path).ToList();
   ```

   Returns

   ```json
   [
     "Risks[0].RiskId",
     "Risks[1].RiskId"
   ]
   ```

   From which you can see that the correct path to use in the original query should have been `"Risks[*].RiskId"`.

Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lwrvdv